# I'm struggling to implement the removeCardsFromHand method in my Uno game, can I please have some suggestions as to how I should approach the method?

Tags: java

So for this method, I am supposed to remove the card that was just played from the player’s hand, while accepting the player (player) and card (index) as arguments.

I know that if I were to remove player 1’s first card, at playerHand[0][0], I would need to shift playerHand[0][1] into the playerHand[0][0] spot and shift any other cards the player had down by one index as well, but I'm not sure how to exactly approach this in my code.

```
    public static int nPlayers;
    public static int currentPlayer;
    public static UnoCard playerHand[][];
    public static UnoCard currentCard;
    public static final int CARDS_IN_DECK = 112;
    public static final int START_HAND = 7;
    public static boolean direction = true; // true for regular direction, false for reverse direction
    public static int winner;

    public static void removeCardFromHand(int p, int idx) {

    }
```

Comment: Are you obliged to use an array? There are other data structures where this shifting isn't necessary.

Comment: I am sadly, keeping the structure as an array is essential for other moving parts of this class.

Comment: More specific to @MarsAtomic question, are you required to use an array to solve this problem. You may have to make changes elsewhere sure. 

A better solution would be to make a player class and encapsulate the logic for the hand there. Each player would have a List<UnoCard> that represents their hand. The removeCardFromHand would simply take an index and the shifting is taken care of by the List. This will help remove some logic from a class that is already keep track of a lot of variables. 

Operating on a Player object is more readable than a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

With an array, you can do something like this

```
public static void removeCardFromHand(int p, int idx) {
    // get the card to remove
    UnoCard removed = playerHand[p][idx];

    // reorder all cards
    for (int i = idx; i <= playerHand.length - 2; i++) {
        playerHand[p][i] = playerHand[p][i + 1];
    }
    // last card is now the second last card, so we dont need it
    playerHand[p][playerHand.length - 1] = null;
}
```

I would sugest to use `ArrayList` instead, which has an `remove` method and is easier to use.